IMPORTRANGE with REGEXREPLACE/REGEXMATCH function
I have dummy data related to product code of books:



XXX
AAA
BB
Document Code
Test Type




P01
BOO
01
BK-001-CR
1. Content Quality Testing    - Proofreading    - Fact-checking    - Final editing2. Design and Layout Testing


P01
BOO
02
BK-002-CR
1. Physical Production Testing2. Distribution Testing


P02
OOK
01
BK-001-CR
1. Content Quality Testing    - Proofreading    - Fact-checking    - Final editing2. Design and Layout Testing


P03
KOO
01
BK-001-RT
1. Content Quality Testing    - Proofreading    - Fact-checking    - Final editing2. Design and Layout Testing



as listed in this link.
I want to clean it up into expected output as follows:



Product Code
Document Code
Test Type




P01.BOO.01P02.OOK.01
BK-001-CR
Content Quality Testing   - Proofreading   - Fact-checking   - Final editing


P01.BOO.01P02.OOK.01
BK-001-CR
Design and Layout Testing


P01.BOO.02
BK-002-CR
Physical Production Testing


P01.BOO.02
BK-002-CR
Distribution Testing


P03.KOO.01
BK-001-RT
Content Quality Testing   - Proofreading   - Fact-checking   - Final editing


P03.KOO.01
BK-001-RT
Design and Layout Testing



as listed in this link.
For the output, I have tried with formula in Product Code column:
=ARRAYFORMULA( 
  TEXTJOIN(" "; TRUE; 
    FILTER(
      IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dIVsBszYwQnELHwu8C7BaamZnQTz2zogzKlrkq72IZQ/edit?gid=0#gid=0"; "Test!B2:B5") & "." & 
      IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dIVsBszYwQnELHwu8C7BaamZnQTz2zogzKlrkq72IZQ/edit?gid=0#gid=0"; "Test!C2:C5") & "." &
      IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dIVsBszYwQnELHwu8C7BaamZnQTz2zogzKlrkq72IZQ/edit?gid=0#gid=0"; "Test!D2:D5"); 
      (REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dIVsBszYwQnELHwu8C7BaamZnQTz2zogzKlrkq72IZQ/edit?gid=0#gid=0"; "Test!F2:F5"); I2) + 
      REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dIVsBszYwQnELHwu8C7BaamZnQTz2zogzKlrkq72IZQ/edit?gid=0#gid=0"; "Test!B2:B5"); H2)) > 0
    )
  )
)

In Document Code column:
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dIVsBszYwQnELHwu8C7BaamZnQTz2zogzKlrkq72IZQ/edit?gid=0#gid=0"; "Test!E2:F5"); "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 CONTAINS '" & I2 & "'")

In Test Type column:
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  UNIQUE(
    FILTER(
      TRIM(
        FLATTEN(
          SPLIT(
            REGEXREPLACE(
              IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dIVsBszYwQnELHwu8C7BaamZnQTz2zogzKlrkq72IZQ/edit?gid=0#gid=0"; "Test!F2:F5"); 
              "\d+\."; 
              "~"
            ); 
            "~"
          )
        )
      ); 
      (TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dIVsBszYwQnELHwu8C7BaamZnQTz2zogzKlrkq72IZQ/edit?gid=0#gid=0"; "Test!F2:F5"); "\d+\."; "~"); "~"))) <> "")
    )
  )
)

However, there is still an error and it still does not match the expected output.

Is there any other formula?

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question (without tags). Also, never link "link"--it's not accessible and the information isn't actually in the link; it's in the linked page.

FWIW, that's not cleaning it up. You're just making it more complicated for other programs or databases.  The original is much more database friendly.


Here's a generalized approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=let(Λ;importrange("1dIVsBszYwQnELHwu8C7BaamZnQTz2zogzKlrkq72IZQ";"B2:F7");Σ;lambda(x;choosecols(Λ;x));a;Σ(1);b;Σ(2);c;Σ(3);d;Σ(4);e;Σ(5);
 reduce(tocol(;1);unique(tocol(d;1));lambda(x;y;vstack(x;reduce(tocol(;1);sequence(max(index(ifna(--regexextract(split(xlookup(y;d;e);char(10));"^\d+")))));lambda(f;q;vstack(f;
 hstack(join(char(10);filter(a&"."&b&"."&c;d=y));y;regexextract(xlookup(y;d;e);"(?s).*"&q&". (.*?)(?:\n"&q+1&". |$)")))))))))



You can also try this array formula:
=ArrayFormula(LET(url,"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mNDf04c51ucs5NOSQG3CRVRdlyQnJ2AvmmIvuIO0FU0/",
              refProdCode,"'Test'!B2:D5",
              refDocCode,"'Test'!E2:E5",
              refTestType,"'Test'!F2:F5",
              prodCode_data,IMPORTRANGE(url,refProdCode),
              docCode_data,IMPORTRANGE(url,refDocCode),
              testType_data,IMPORTRANGE(url,refTestType),
              prodCode,TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(prodCode_data),,9^9))," ",".")),
              testType_split,SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(testType_data,"[0-9]*\.","#"),"#"),
              concatAll,prodCode&"@"&docCode_data&"#"&testType_split,
              breakdown,SPLIT(FLATTEN(concatAll),"@"),
              initialSummary,QUERY(breakdown,"SELECT Col1,MIN(Col1) GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col2 LABEL MIN(Col1) ''",0),
              getHeader,CHOOSEROWS(initialSummary,1),
              getBody,QUERY(initialSummary,"OFFSET 1"),
              concatBody,REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(getBody,,9^9))," ",CHAR(10)),
              finalProdDocCodes,SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(getHeader),"#"),
              final,QUERY(HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(concatBody),finalProdDocCodes),"ORDER BY Col1,Col2 OFFSET 1",0),
              final)

)

Make sure to replace the url and the references.
